# URL Scheme to open VF page in Salesforce 1 iOS app

Tags: visualforce, salesforce1-app, email-template

Is it possible to open a VF page in Salesforce1 iOS app coming from a link in an email?

If not, do you have any workaround ideas to make this work?

Comment: So you want a user, who has received an email in their standard mail app on their mobile device, to be able to tap that link and open the S1 mobile app, and have it arrive right on your VF page? Definitely not standard.

Comment: Actually it is possible. We were able to make it work after a while of research. But, there are still issues/limitations i.e. we still cannot append url parameters with the link to SF1. we really need it

Comment: Yeah...the not-standard bit would be getting to the specific VF page you want. The rest of it isn't too hard. The thing to realize is that Salesforce 1 (or more to the point, the underlying aura framework it is built on) doesn't understand actions the same way the rest of the UI does, it works with events. I think the way you might have some success is if you can hook into the force:navigateToUrl event. Sorry, but too busy today to try it myself, but I think you might be after something like `com.salesforce.salesforce1://force/navigateToUrl`...the tricky bit is the url param again.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to **view** a record, you can use:

```
com.salesforce.salesforce1://entity/view?entityId={!record.Id}
```

Note that this only allows you to force SalesForce1 to perform the `View` action. You can override this action, but that may have more serious consequences and not be desirable.

Comment: I am now able to open a VF page using  <b> com.salesforce.salesforce1://entity/view?entityId=apex/myVFpage?id={!Case.Id} </b> but I noticed it cannot pass the id parameter. Do you know if it's possible, or is my parameter assignment wrong?

Comment: Just use the merge value `{!Case.Id}`

Comment: So what I did is correct? I did put the ?id={!Case.id} because myVFpage has a standardcontroller Case. the reason why I need the id. But unfortunately, it seems the id parameter is blank after opening up the VF page :(

Comment: I don't think you can access an apex page that way - this url scheme document doesn't include any reference to accessing apex pages: https://na7.my.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce1_url_schemes_ios.pdf

Comment: @CaspNZ I have confirmed it to work in production environments.

Comment: You mean the apex/myVFpage?id={!Case.Id} version? If so, that's pretty cool.

Comment: @CaspNZ Maybe you're responding to his comments? If you look in my answer, I specifically state that you can do this with a custom `View` action.

Comment: Yes, nevermind my comments - I think I was confused - I agree with you - I even upvoted ;)

Comment: Haha thanks. Unfortunate that such a seemingly simple request is still such a pain!